# yAxis labels are being cut off in ngEchars (Echarts)

Tags: angularjs, charts, bar-chart, chart.js

I have user ngEcharts (angularjs plugin of Echarts). When i implement bar chart yaxis labels are cutting off.[image]

can anyone point me on the direction to how to prevent this or increase yAxis label area or decrease chart area?

Comment: Can you add code that recreates this problem? (A JSFiddle would be nice too.)

Comment: You may set grid: http://echarts.baidu.com/option.html#grid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Ovilia's link i was able to  remove cut off using it's **grid** property.

It has **containLabel** property.

Once i set **containLabel** it to true, i didn't need to set grid size. it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the chart init configuration object. It will fix the cut-off labels

```
grid: { containLabel: true },
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing truncation issue after implementing above accepted answer.

Add **left: 0;** (or some positive integer value) to grid property along with **containLabel: true;**

i.e

```
grid: {containLabel: true, left: 0};
```